# How can I convert HRESULT to Readable errors in sql

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm bulk importing (sql) data into staging tables but getting error like:

`'Row 3 File Offset 311 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005'` in my error.txt file.

This error shows the row and position where error occurred but not the exact cause. Is there any way to know specific causes of the issue, when such errors are generated while importing data?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using SQL Server

Comment: You can feed those error codes to the win32 API function [FormatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/retrieving-error-messages) to get a text message in your local language - which is something the bcp.exe utility really should be doing for you anyway. In this case it resolves to an unhelpful "-2147467259, 0x80004005, Unspecified error"

Comment: In your case I'd be checking the format of the data on row 3 to confirm that it is convertible to the data types of your target table. Things like date/datetime strings in the wrong format, numeric values containing decimal characters when the target column is `int`, etc.